Rotary encoder issues
I currently have a 600 p/r encoder hooked up to a pi 4.  Seems to work ok, but due to the pi OS (bookworm) it usually misses some counts.  From what I read, it seems that there are 2 possible ways to fix this.
The first, and probably best, is to use an external encoder counter such as the LS7366R Quadrature Encoder Buffer from superdroid robot, or use an arduino as a counter buffer which is then queried by the pi.
The second method is to use pigpio to read it directly with the pi.
Both of these methods are causing me a headache.
I am unable find a simple LS7366R buffer card that is in stock or doesn't cost way more then I can justify.  I have found LS7366R double, triple and quadruple cards, just not single cards.  I could use a double, triple or quadruple card but I'd like to keep the cost down.  I also don't have the capacity or ability to get an LS7366R chip and build my own card.
I'm a little confused on the pigpio method, as I understand that pigpio doesn't have an issue with the OS "multitasking" and hence wouldn't miss any counts.  I can't really find any sources that say this outright so I'm not sure this is the best way to go.
Any help that can be provided will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
gwfami

See Tour to see how this site works
and How do I ask a good question?

Why not try?  See https://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_rotary_encoder_py

Thanks Joan,  I have tried that.  Just not certain if pigpio would prevent missed counts.
